# Strange output when compiling c++ code. Any Ideas?

Tags: c++

When i compile my code i get a set of errors that appear to related to the output files as in the .o file.  I'm not sure why these sorts of errors would occur. Any Ideas?

```
/tmp/ccjPLJVV.o: In function `PubSub::~PubSub()':
Video_process.cpp:(.text._ZN6PubSubD2Ev[_ZN6PubSubD5Ev]+0x12): undefined reference to `vtable for PubSub'
/tmp/ccjPLJVV.o: In function `main':
Video_process.cpp:(.text.startup+0x34): undefined reference to `vtable for PubSub'
Video_process.cpp:(.text.startup+0xeb): undefined reference to `PubSub::run()'
/tmp/ccjPLJVV.o:(.rodata._ZTI13Video_process[typeinfo for Video_process]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for PubSub'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is essentially the output i'm getting when I attempt to compile.

Comment: @birryree oooops sorry. well, why did'nt you answer this? It's odd, but this type of questions comes here *all the time*.

Comment: @Walter - Lucian already answered it as I was editing the question.

Comment: Did you perhaps forget to simply link against the source code defining class `PubSub`?

Comment: oh...okay ya...wow fail...thanks

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have unimplemented `virtual` methods.

```
class PubSub
{
    //virtual destructors, although pure
    //MUST have an implementation
    virtual ~PubSub() = 0 { } 

    /*virtual?*/ void Run(); // <--- have you implemented this one?
};
```

Comment: k so the run method isn't declared as virtual in the header file of PubSub. So I shouldnt have to implement it right

Comment: @user1415372 of course you should. You should implement all methods that you use.

Comment: um...sry what I meant was the run function was implemented already...I meant that I don't need to override the function in the subclass.

Comment: hm...okay...well after looking through the code everything seems to be implemented so are there any other possible reasons why this would fail

Answer (score 0):

this is an error message from the *linker*, not the compiler. The linker cannot find some symbols which are declared, but not defined, in some files it tries to link together to make (most likely) an executable. The solution is to provide the definitions, i.e. the (compiled) code with those definitions. That code may already exist and you just have to "link against it" (tell the linker to search for symbols there) or may not, in which case you have to provide it...

for example, add the file defining the implementations of class `PubSub` to the linker/compiler command line should help ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've implemented the method, but you have not linked it. If you're using GCC, *-o* flag is your friend; all your class .o files must be specified when compiling the main.cpp.